# Android. Real user registration in app

Tags: android, security

I have an app with registration. It is need to be protected from multiple registration from cheater. I.e. cheater can write the script, where he was register many users (sending requests to server for registration). There is device's built in Google account. Maybe it is possible to check via Google that account corresponds to device id?

Comment: You can identify the user by the unique IMEI.

Comment: A cheater can send my server what he want as IMEI.

Comment: A cheater can also make two Google accounts ;)

Comment: Less than 20 accounts is not big problem.